# Can we compare benchmark/performance of binary operators?

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, benchmarking

My question is about the performance (execution time / benchmark) of binary operators, can we say by example that performing `a + b` is faster than `a % b`.
My question is not limited to only those operators (+ and %) but also:

- Additive operators (+ and -)
- Multiplicative operators (*, /, %...)
- Comparative operators (<, >, <=...)
- BITWISE and shift operators (<<, <<<...)
- ...

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148653/bit-operations-c

Comment: If you want detailed information: compile the code in question to assembly, look at the assembly and see [*Instruction tables: Lists of instruction latencies, throughputs and micro-operation breakdowns for Intel, AMD and VIA CPUs* on agner.org](http://www.agner.org).

Comment: write a small program, start a clock, do the same action millions of times, stop the clock and compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance of these operators depends on the platform. If an operation expresses with a “slow” operator can be implemented with a “fast” operator, you can generally expect the compiler to pick this up and emit fast code. Do not use “faster” operands just because someone told you they are faster without benchmarking.

Generally though, operators can be classified in speed roughly according to the following scale:

1. Zero cycles: Addition immediately preceding dereferencing such as in an array expression `a[b]` is usually free. Unary `+` is free, too.
2. One cycle: For integer operands: binary `+`, `-`, `<<`, `>>`, `&`, `|`, `^`, unary `-`, `~`, casts between integer types or pointers, if the result is not used numerically: `!`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `!=`, `&&`, `||`
3. Three to four cycles: binary `*` on integer operands, on floating point operands: binary `+`, `-`
4. 20 cycles (?): integer binary `/`, `%`
5. 50 cycles (?): floating point `/`, `fmod`

Your mileage may vary, do not rely on this table, benchmark when in doubt.

Comment: This is a bit misleading because it doesn't account for multiple dispatch, instruction reordering, etc. Also, floating point ops often vary in spped with the values of the operands.

Comment: @Gene Which is why I say “Your mileage may vary.”

Comment: @FUZxxl so if I implement an algorithm using SHIFT and BITWISE operators (one cycle), it will be more optimized than if it's implemented using / or % (20 cycles)?

Comment: @WaelBoutglay Potentially. The compiler is going to optimize stuff like `a / 32` into `a >> 5` though, so you shouldn't worry about such small details.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of additions to FUZxxl's answer:

- on modern Intels and AMDs both + and * have roughly the same (very fast) throughput, but * usually has higher latency. Throughput is how often you can issue a command, and latency is how long you'd have to wait before the results are ready (while the CPU executes something else out of order)
- some RISC CPUs have pretty expensive shifts (namely, the ones used on Xbox360 and PS3)
- they "fixed" the division some time ago, and it's no longer as horribly slow as it used to be. I think FP division is about 16 clocks now (integer might actually be slower)
- while comparisons are all fast per se, conditional jumps can be very slow if they are mispredicted (since the CPU will have to dump everything that it would have predictively executed ahead). Whether the CPU manages to predict the results of a comparison depends on how random they are (when the same check is executed many times). However, even if they tend to follow a pattern, each jump uses up a branch prediction slot, so it may evict another jump from it, and that other branch would suffer the misprediction penalty instead. In other words, comparisons can be pretty expensive.